# RMSE in interpolation

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation, kriging, inverse-distance-weighted

I am doing interpolation for a chemical concentration in loamy soil across a very large arable land. I used simple kriging, IDW and EBK. The data distribution was skewed so I had RMSE of close 100 for each of the interpolation methods. I did a log transformation to normalize the data distribution and ended up with similar RMSE for IDW and even larger RMSE for simple Kriging and EBK.

I am working in ArcGIS Pro.

I want to know if I can use mean and other statistics to explain the accuracy of the predicted values other than the RMSE?

Should RMSE always be close to zero (That is what I know so far) and in my circumstance if I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question is more appropriate for [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). You have done GIS works but your ultimate problem is related to stats.